# Adding and repeating a list in a Data Frame for each ID in R

Tags: r, list, repeat

I have the following data frame (DATA) with names of region (120 regions), IPC class (patent), and number of patents per IPC per Region

```
(DATA)
REGION   IPC   Count
AT11    B29C    15
AT11    B32B    22
AT11    C02F    17
AT11    C09K    26
.........
FI19    A01C    67
FI19    G09G    13
FI19    H01F    32
```

I have a data frame with all the 594 IPC CLASS

```
(ALLIPC)
A01B
A01C
A01D
A01F
...
H05K
```

I would like to create a dataframe DATA2 with all the 594 IPC class from ALLIPC for each region even when the region has no count in it, so when the region  has no IPC class in DATA it becomes 0 and when the region has in DATA a count to keep the original count for each IPC

```
(DATA2)
REGION   IPC   Count
AT11    A01B    0
AT11    A01C    0
AT11    A01D    0
...
AT11    B29C    15
AT11    B32B    22
AT11    C02F    17
AT11    C09K    26
.........
FI19    A01B    0
FI19    A01C    67
FI19    A01D    0
....
FI19    G09G    13
FI19    H01F    32
```

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(DATA)
setDT(ALLIPC)
DATA <- DATA[CJ(IPC = ALLIPC$IPC, REGION, unique = TRUE), 
             on = .(IPC, REGION), 
             ][, Count := fifelse(is.na(Count), 0L, Count)
               ][order(REGION)]
DATA[]
    REGION  IPC Count
 1:   AT11 A01B     0
 2:   AT11 A01C     0
 3:   AT11 A01D     0
 4:   AT11 A01F     0
 5:   AT11 B29C    15
...
21:   FI19 H01F    32
22:   FI19 H05K     0
    REGION  IPC Count
```

Reproducible input data:

```
DATA <- data.frame(
   REGION = c("AT11", "AT11", "AT11", "AT11", "FI19", "FI19", "FI19"), 
   IPC = c("B29C", "B32B", "C02F", "C09K", "A01C", "G09G", "H01F"), 
   Count = c(15L, 22L, 17L, 26L, 67L, 13L, 32L),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
ALLIPC = data.frame(
  IPC = c(
    "A01B", "A01C", "A01D", "A01F", "H05K", "B29C", "B32B", "C02F", "C09K", "G09G", "H01F"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
df3 <- merge(df2, df, by = intersect(names(df), names(df2)), all.x = TRUE)

df3$Count <- replace(df3$Count, is.na(df3$Count), 0)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  REGION = c("AT11", "AT11", "AT11", "AT11", "FI19", "FI19", "FI19"), 
  IPC = c("B29C", "B32B", "C02F", "C09K", "A01C", "G09G", "H01F"), 
  Count = c(15L, 22L, 17L, 26L, 67L, 13L, 32L),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df2 = data.frame(
  IPC = c(
    "A01B", "A01C", "A01D", "A01F", "H05K", "B29C", "B32B", "C02F", "C09K", "G09G", "H01F"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
```

)